# zend framework 2/3 multicheckbox disable isEmpty errorMessage

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-form, zend-framework3, zend-validate

By default a multicheckbox element triggers an error message when none of the options are selected:

```
 array (size=1)
  'checkbox' => 
    array (size=1)
      'isEmpty' => string 'Value is required and can't be empty' (length=36)
```

I found out that the message can be disabled using the function `getInputFilterSpecification`:

```
class MyForm extends Form  implements InputFilterProviderInterface{

  private $inputFilter;

  public function __construct($name = null){

    parent::__construct($name);


    $this->add([
                'name' => 'checkbox',
                'type' => 'checkbox',
                'attributes' => [],
                'options' => [
                             'value_options' =>[
                                                [
                                                'value' => '0',
                                                //'selected' => true,
                                                'label' => 'One',
                                                'label_attributes'=>[],
                                                'attributes' => [],
                                                ],

                                                [
                                                'value' => '1',
                                                'label' => 'Two',
                                                'label_attributes'=>[],
                                                'attributes' => [],
                                                ],
                                                [
                                                'value' => '2',
                                                'label' => 'Three',
                                                'label_attributes'=>[],
                                                'attributes' => [],
                                                ],
                             ],
                ],
    ]);


  }//construct

   public function getInputFilterSpecification() {
        return array(
         'checkbox'=>['required'=>false,],
        );  
    }


}//class
```

The only "issue" with this approach is that you have to specify name and the relative option for all the instances of the multicheckbox element; having 10 different multicheckboxes the inputfilter specifications would be something like:

```
public function getInputFilterSpecification() {
   return array(
     'checkbox1'=>['required'=>false,],
     'checkbox2'=>['required'=>false,],
     'checkbox3'=>['required'=>false,],
     ...   
   );  
}
```

...and ok it's not that bad but it seems pretty dumb since the element (and/or all the value options) accepts the attribute `required` but then is practically treated as if it was required and **that makes no sense at all**.

Where does that message come from? It seems a preassigned notEmpty validator but I haven't found any trace of it in the Zend's `Mulicheckbox` class or into the parent `Checkbox` class.

Isn't there really no better approach to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer on my own.

Zend's Multicheckbox element extends the Checkbox element which implements `InputProviderInterface`.

And in Checkbox (line 165) there is:

```
public function getInputSpecification()
{
    $spec = [
        'name' => $this->getName(),
        'required' => true,
    ];

    if ($validator = $this->getValidator()) {
        $spec['validators'] = [
            $validator,
        ];
    }

    return $spec;
}
```

That required parameter is retrieved from the `Zend\InputFilter\Input` class and if true (always true) a notEmpty validator is added.

Ergo: there's no way to change that behaviour throug the element's options (and again: that's dumb).

---

### Anyway, something can be done by using a custom element that extends multicheckbox (and that's actually what I'm already doing, for other reasons):

```
namespace Form\Form\Element;

use Zend\InputFilter\InputProviderInterface;
use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\ViewHelperProviderInterface;
use Zend\Form\Element\MultiCheckbox;

class BootstrapMultiCheckbox extends MultiCheckbox implements  ViewHelperProviderInterface, InputProviderInterface{

  protected $attributes = [
                          'type' => 'bootstrapMultiCheckbox',
                          ];

  public function getViewHelperConfig(){return array('Form\Form\View\Helper\BootstrapMultiCheckboxHelper', null);}

  public function getInputSpecification(){
    $spec = [
            'name' => $this->getName(),
            'required' => false,
            ];

    if ($validator = $this->getValidator()) {

      $spec['validators'] = [$validator,];
    }

    return $spec;
  }

}
```

I just copied the `getInputSpecification` function from the original Checkbox element and set required to false. This way there's no need anymore to specify the required parameter into the form's `getInputFilterSpecification` function.

Obviously this solution makes sense if you're already using a custom version of multicheckbox, otherwise...make your own considerations.

---

### UPDATE: handle the element's required attribute, practical use

Basically you will handle the required attribute this way (here for a custom Radio element):

```
//Form __construct:

$this->add([
                'name' => 'radio',
                'type' => BootstrapRadio::class,
                'attributes' => ['required' => true,],
                'options' => [
                             'value_options' =>[...],
                ],
    ]);
```

Then:

```
//BootstrapRadio Element:
public function getInputSpecification(){

    //If required==true, then the notEmpty validator will be added (see above)
    $required=$this->getAttribute('required');

    $spec = [
            'name' => $this->getName(),
            'required' => $required,
            ];

    if ($validator = $this->getValidator()) {

      $spec['validators'] = [$validator,];
    }

    return $spec;
  }
```

Alternatively **you might want to assign the required attribute to a few options only** (senseless for a radio element):

```
//Form __construct:

$this->add([
                'name' => 'checkbox',
                'type' => BootstrapMultiCheckbox::class,
                'options' => [
                             'value_options' =>[
                                                [
                                                'value' => '0',
                                                'label' => 'One',
                                                ],

                                                [
                                                'value' => '1',
                                                'label' => 'Two',
                                                'attributes' => ['required' => true,],
                                                ],
                                                [
                                                'value' => '2',
                                                'label' => 'Three',
                                                'attributes' => ['required' => true,],
                                                ],
                             ],
                ],
    ]);
```

Then:

```
//Custom element:
namespace Form\Form\Element;

use Zend\InputFilter\InputProviderInterface;
use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\ViewHelperProviderInterface;
use Zend\Form\Element\MultiCheckbox;
use Zend\Validator\NotEmpty;

use Form\Form\Validator\BootstrapMulticheckboxValidator;

class BootstrapMultiCheckbox extends MultiCheckbox implements  ViewHelperProviderInterface, InputProviderInterface{

  protected $attributes = [
                          'type' => 'bootstrapMultiCheckbox',
                          ];

  protected $requiredValues=false;

  public function getViewHelperConfig(){return array('Form\Form\View\Helper\BootstrapMultiCheckboxHelper', null);}

  public function getInputSpecification(){


    $required=$this->setIsRequired();

    $spec = [
            'name' => $this->getName(),
            'required' => $required,
            ];

    if ($validator = $this->getValidator()) {

      $spec['validators'] = $this->requiredValues ? [$validator, new BootstrapMulticheckboxValidator($this->requiredValues)] : [$validator];
    }

    return $spec;
  }

  public function setIsRequired(){

    $value=$this->getValue();

    if(!$value && $this->getAttribute('required')){return true;}

    foreach ($this->getValueOptions() as $key => $option){
      if(isset($option['attributes']['required'])){$this->requiredValues[$key]=$option['value'];}
    }

    if(!$value && $this->requiredValues){return true;}

    return false;
  }

}
```

And finally:

```
//custom validator
namespace Form\Form\Validator;

use Traversable;
use Zend\Stdlib\ArrayUtils;
use Zend\Validator\AbstractValidator;
use Zend\Validator\NotEmpty;

class BootstrapMulticheckboxValidator extends AbstractValidator
{

    const IS_EMPTY = 'isEmpty';

    protected $requiredValues;

    protected $messageTemplates = [
        self::IS_EMPTY => 'Value is required and can\'t be empty',

    ];

    public function __construct($requiredValues)
    {
      $this->requiredValues=$requiredValues;

      parent::__construct(null);
    }

    public function isValid($values)
    {

       foreach($this->requiredValues as $required){
         if(!in_array($required, $values)){
           $this->error(self::IS_EMPTY);
           return false;
         }
       }
       return true;
    }
}
```

---

**Note:** depending on how you render your custom elements you might want to disable browser's validation by adding the novalidate attribute to your form:

```
class BootstrapForm extends Form  implements InputFilterProviderInterface{

  private $inputFilter;

  public function __construct($name = null){

    parent::__construct($name);

    $this->setAttribute('novalidate',true);

    $this->add([
                'name' => 'checkbox',
    [...]
```